# Ember Router logs error: "Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, client-side

Fairly straight-forward Ember question here, (I hope!).

I have a simple Ember-data setup. One App has many Versions. Here's my App model:

```
App.App = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  publicKey: DS.attr('string'),
  versions: DS.hasMany('App.Version', { key: 'version_ids' })
});
```

My router is fairly simple:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'hash',
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'dashboard'
    }),
    dashboard: ...,
    app: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/:app_id',
      connectOutlets: function(router, app) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('appTest', app);
      },

      index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
          appTestController = router.get('appTestController');
          appTestController.connectOutlet('addCommentOutlet', 'addComment', {});
          appTestController.connectOutlet('versions', appTestController.get('content.versions'));
        }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

And the views and controllers look like this:

```
App.AppTestView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app_test'
});

App.VersionsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'versions'
});

App.AppTestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

App.VersionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
});
```

When I run it unfortunately I get the error: `an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <App.Version:ember519>`.

Interestingly, if I add brackets around `[appTestController.get('content.versions')]` in the router it doesn't complain and creates an array with the first Version object correctly. But it doesn't seem to want to show more than one object.

Any tips?

Comment: The error is straight forward, it says that App.Version is not an instanceOf Array, It looks like you are trying to set an Object to content property of Collection View(whose code I can't see in the question), which is of type Ember.Array()...Clear me If I am wrong

Comment: That's the funny thing though. I want to sent the content array with an array of content: except `appTestController.get('content.versions')` is returning a single object instead of an array?!

Comment: appTestController is ObjectController or ArrayController ? & also how are you querying the store ?

Comment: ObjectController. I'm using Ember-data (so everything you see here is everything I've got on the database/store end). I've just figured it out though! Will post an answer.

Comment: Just as a tip for future questions: if you include a JSFiddle which demonstrates your problem, it's much more likely that you'll get an answer...

Comment: Sounds good. I started a JSFiddle but it was taking me a while to get the libraries right. (I was doing it from scratch). I just found this template though for Ember: http://jsfiddle.net/qKXJt/. Do you know of any others / more recent ones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end, it wasn't the models, view objects or controllers! It wasn't even the router.

It was `versions.handlebars`. I had a loop within a loop in my template, as below:

```
{{#each version in controller}}
  Version here
  {{#each comment in version}}
    {{comment.text}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I'd incorrectly written:

```
each comment in version
```

... where I'd meant to write:

```
each comment in version.comments
```

:) That explains the error message. Hope this helps somebody else!